# converting json data to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default2.aspx/myMethod",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function OnSuccess(response) {
            var str = response.d;
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(str);
            for(i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++)
            {
                jsonObj[i]="{"+jsonObj[i]+"}"
            }
            jsonObj = "[" + jsonObj + "]";
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
```

What I recevied in jsonObj is the javascript array of images path. I pass this array to a image slider to show images but it shows undefined i.e not displayed the images 
the result of jsonObj is

```
[{'src: ../img/kota-image/11.jpg'},{'src: ../img/kota-image/12.jpg'},{'src: ../img/kota-image/13.jpg'},{'src: ../img/kota-image/14.jpg'},{'src: ../img/kota-image/15.jpg'},{'src: ../img/kota-image/197.jpg'},{'src: ../img/kota-image/2706.jpg'},{'src: ../img/kota-image/9.jpg'},{'src: ../img/kota-image/DSC_0825.JPG'},{'src: ../img/kota-image/kota.jpg'}]
```

my image slider is

```
jR3DCarousel = $('.jR3DCarouselGallery').jR3DCarousel({
        width: $(window).width(),       /* largest allowed width */
        height: 670,        /* largest allowed height */
        slides: jsonObj/* array of images source */,
        "animationDuration": 1500,
        "animationInterval": 2500,
    });
```

Comment: `{'src: ../img/kota-image/12.jpg'}` is not valid javascript.

Comment: Why do not you use jsonObj directly after parsing it?

Comment: please add the format of the receiving data and the structure of the target data.

Comment: You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Just create an array of objects, not strings. Use `JSON.stringify()` to turn it into JSON if you need.

Comment: Yes {'src: ../img/kota-image/12.jpg'} is not valid javascript.So I changed it to {'src':' ../img/kota-image/12.jpg'} but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I think, you don't need this loop:

```
  for(i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++)
  {
      jsonObj[i]="{"+jsonObj[i]+"}"
  }
  jsonObj = "[" + jsonObj + "]";
```

`var jsonObj = JSON.parse(str);` is already an array.

Try the code below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default2.aspx/myMethod",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function OnSuccess(response) {
        var str = response.d;
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(str); 
        console.log( jsonObj  );
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

If you wanted to convert the object to pure array, you can do it this way.

```
  success: function OnSuccess(response) {
        var str     = response.d;
        var data    = JSON.parse(str);  
        var jsonObj = $.map(data, function(value, index) {
              return [value];
        });
       console.log(jsonObj );
   }
```

Comment: more than that, not only he doesn't need, but that will for sure break the way the object can be used, as it results in a string with something like `"[[object Object],[object Object]]"`

Comment: Actually what I want to ask you the path I received is not display the images in image slider.It shows undefined.Although when I display the image path is correct.I just want to load the images dynamically from the folder using ajax and json.

Answer (score 0):

Your json seems to be improperly formatted.
Change it from

```
[{'src: ../img/kota-image/11.jpg'},{'src: ../img/kota-image/12.jpg'}]
```

to

```
[{'src': '../img/kota-image/11.jpg'},{'src':
 '../img/kota-image/12.jpg'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to use like this

```
[{'src': '../img/kota-image/11.jpg'},{'src': '../img/kota-image/12.jpg'},{'src': '../img/kota-image/13.jpg'},{'src': '../img/kota-image/14.jpg'},{'src': '../img/kota-image/15.jpg'},{'src': '../img/kota-image/197.jpg'},{'src': '../img/kota-image/2706.jpg'},{'src': '../img/kota-image/9.jpg'},{'src': '../img/kota-image/DSC_0825.JPG'},{'src': '../img/kota-image/kota.jpg'}]
```